# How to get the textbox value in ascx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

In my project I have 3 user controls, those are displayed in master page. When I entered the value in textbox it doesn't getting current value, it will display previous value.
Code:

1st Data Bound:

```
  protected void dlFirstZone_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
  {
    if (((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) && (e.Item.DataItem != null))
    {
        using (GroceriesServiceClient groceriesServiceClient = new GroceriesServiceClient())
        {
            HomeMaster pp = (HomeMaster)e.Item.DataItem;
            int prdItem = pp.ProductId;
            ShoppingCart shopingCartParameter = new ShoppingCart();
            //if (pp.DisplayOrder == 1)
            //{
            Products products = new Products();
            if (basePage.BasePageWebSession != null)
            {
                shopingCartParameter.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(basePage.BasePageWebSession.UserId);
                cartlist = groceriesServiceClient.ShoppingCart_UserProductsList(shopingCartParameter);

                var td = (from c in cartlist
                          where c.ProductId == prdItem
                          select c);

                if (td.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                   TextBox txtQtyDataview = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtQty");
                   txtQtyDataview.Text = td.First().Quantity.ToString();
                }
            }
            //}
            //else 
        }
    }
}
```

2nd ItemCommand event handler:

```
protected void dlProduct_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
   HomeMaster q = (HomeMaster)e.Item.DataItem;
   if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
   {
      using (GroceriesServiceClient gsc = new GroceriesServiceClient())
      {
         ShoppingCart shoppingcart = new ShoppingCart();
         shoppingcart.UserId = basePage.BasePageWebSession.UserId;
         shoppingcart.UserName = basePage.BasePageWebSession.UserName;
         shoppingcart.ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToInt32(dlProductDataView.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]));
         TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtQty");

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1.Text))
            shoppingcart.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);
         else
            shoppingcart.Quantity = 1;
            shoppingcart = gsc.ShoppingCart_InsertOrUpdate(shoppingcart);
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);    
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the controls in a updatepanel and updated every event? I think the values ​​are only changed the front end when there is postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use findControl to find the textbox within a user control, like this (assuming you have a textbox called tb1 in a userconrol called uc1:

```
 me.uc1.findControl("tb1").text
```

The better way, though, is to expose a public function that can be called to return the value:

In UserControl, create a public function:

```
public function getValue() as string
       return me.tb1.text
   end Function
```

Then you can access it from any page or control that has a reference to the user control:

```
dim whatsMyName as string = me.uc1.getValue()
```